# Executing Py file in Python Service

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I create a windows service with a code snippet found [here](http://ryrobes.com/stuff/py_service.py)

I've installed and started it, but nothing happens, it has to call another py file but never happens, here's the code into the loop of the SvcDoRun:

```
while 1:

     rc = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop, self.timeout)
     # Check to see if self.hWaitStop happened
     if rc == win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:
        servicemanager.LogInfoMsg("SomeShortNameVersion - STOPPED!")  #For Event Log
        break
     else:
             try:
                 win32api.WinExec("python cdrDB_Collect.py")
             except:
                 pass
```

I tried os.system() and execfile(). Same result, even I tried win32api.WinExec("notepad.exe") to ensure it wasn't a problem of my py file, didn't work, no fancy notepad in my desktop...

Comment: are you sure `WinExec` is even called? you should add some more logging to see what exactly happens.

Comment: @mata Yep, I added a couple of messages to show the flow of the code, before & after the win32api.WinExec(), both of them are displayed in the windows event log